# Laravel Collection groupBy multiple and average an element on the second grouping

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-collection

I am using groupBy successfully on my query to group by two elements.

This is the code:

```
App\Groupshot::findOrNew(4)
    ->load('snapshots.answers.question.tags','snapshots.participant')
    ->answers->groupBy([
        function ($item, $key) {
            return [$item->question->tags()->first()->name];
        },
        function ($item, $key) {
            return [$item->participant->id];
        },
    ]);
```

I’ve previously used map() alongside groupBy to sum a grouped element. In this instance I want to sum the answer score (answer). I'm struggling to apply this approach on the second grouped collection when used above.

Something like this perhaps:

```
->map(function ($row) {
        return $row->first()->sum('answer');
    });
```

If I apply the above to my initial query I get:

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2542
     all: [
       "FEAR" => 6,
       "RAGE" => 22,
       "PANIC/GRIEF" => 2,
       "PLAY" => 3,
     ],
   }
```

What I'm looking for.. sum the second groupby nested query...

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2542
     all: [
       "FEAR" => [Bob => 5, Bill => 2, Ben => 1 ],
       "RAGE" => [Bob => 2, Bill => 1, Ben => 1 ],
       "PANIC/GRIEF" => [Bob => 4, Bill =>3, Ben => 4 ],
       "PLAY" => [Bob => 5, Bill =>3, Ben => 1 ],
     ],
   }
```

Comment: I suggest that you do this in steps. Do the first group by  will give you tag names as keys pointing to collections. The you can do a map on that and in which you group by participant then map to sum. Something like this pseudo code: `$answers->groupBy(tag)->map($item->groupBy(participant)->map(sum))`

Answer (score 1):

Huge thanks to @Michael in the comments for pointing me in this direction. As he suggests, breaking this into parts helped and then wrapping the seconding grouping and sum within the second map.

It's a thing of beauty. Here is the code:

```
App\Groupshot::findOrNew(4)
    ->load('snapshots.answers.question.tags', 'snapshots.participant')
    ->answers->groupBy([
        function ($item, $key) {
            return [$item->question->tags()->first()->name];
        },
    ])
    ->map(function ($row) {
        return $row
            ->groupBy([
                function ($item, $key) {
                    return [$item->participant->FullName];
                },
            ])
            ->map(function ($row) {
                return $row->sum('answer');
            });
    });
```

and the result

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4354
     all: [
       "FEAR" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3670
         all: [
           "Gavin Ellis" => 6,
           "Naomi Lloyd" => 10,
           "Jonathan Walsh" => 18,
           "Reece Kelly" => 17,
           "Connor Wood" => 3,
           "Keith Price" => 4,
           "Joe Phillips" => 5,
           "Bradley Clarke" => 6,
           "Superadministrator Superadministrator" => 6,
           "Elsie Reynolds" => 12,
         ],
       },
       "RAGE" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3972
         all: [
           "Gavin Ellis" => 22,
           "Naomi Lloyd" => 10,
           "Jonathan Walsh" => 12,
           "Reece Kelly" => 29,
           "Connor Wood" => 13,
           "Keith Price" => 10,
           "Joe Phillips" => 17,
           "Bradley Clarke" => 25,
           "Superadministrator Superadministrator" => 6,
           "Elsie Reynolds" => 10,
         ],
       },
```